# How to make streambuilder await?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am build Flutter app with Firebase login but have issue with checking login status. On startup app must check if user logged in or not so it can show correct page. If logged in show homepage (different for different user role). If not, show login page.

I am use `StreamBuilder` in RootPage of app for this but problem is app must first check user info with Firestore db so it know what type of user is logged in and then can route to correct page. Problem is I no find way to make `StreamBuilder` wait for this function to check user info before move on. So the conditionals which operate on the values returned by function are not evaluate correctly. Here is code:

```
    body: StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: _auth.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return new SplashScreen();
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData && getUserDetailsComplete == true) {
          _getUserDetails();

          if (isAdmin == true) {
            return new AdminScreen();
          } else if (isAdmin == false) {
            return new HomeScreen();
          }
        } else {
          return new RootPage();
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

You see I have make workaround for now by: 1. Return RootPage in else statement so it loop until one of conditionals is satisfied and 2. Set boolean to true when function _getUserDetails is complete and add to conditional so widget know when function is completed. But this make app startup slow and not good style.

Anyone know better way to do?

Comment: There is no such thing a waiting in `build()`. Just return a progress bar, spinner, empty Container, ... until data becomes available.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for reply! So this is only way? Must keep looping through streambuilder until function is complete and value returned?

Comment: The only other way is to not using `StreamBuilder`. You can as well listen to the Stream in `initState()` and set the state with `setState()` when the status was updated. But this way you still need to render alternative content until that happens.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks. I have try show spinner while function is executing but if I put as conditional then it stay spinning forever. For example: if(getUserDetailsComplete == false) {return spinner}. Where do I put this spinner?

Comment: assuming your _auth call is an implementation of FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged then be careful - it doesn't work as you would expect inside of a StreamBuilder if you're using it a landing page for runApp().  it won't pick up all changes, whereas creating a .listen on that will

Comment: @blaneyneil Thanks for warning! I am try .listen now. But I have issue (my comment on answer below)

Answer (score 1):

you can use *.then* and *.getIdToken* for user detail in token and claims

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> claims = {}; 
Auth.onAuthStateChanged.map((firebaseUser) {
  firebaseUser
      .getIdToken()
      .then((idTokenResult) => {
            if (idTokenResult.claims != null)
              {claims = idTokenResult.claims}
          })
      .catchError((e) => {print(e)});
```

more info about use custom claims for access control : [firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StatefulWidget. In the state of your widget, include a Widget object. In `initState`, you can store a placeholder Widget (a CircularProgressINnc, or something), and call a function that does some checking in Firebase. Make sure this function is `async`, since it does networking, which has to be done on a separate thread. At the end of this function, just call setState and replace the placeholder widget with a widget of choice. It would look something like this:

```
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  Widget _screen;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _screen = CircularProgressIndicator();

    _doSomeFirebaseChecking();
  }

  void _doSomeFirebaseChecking() async {
    // Add your code that performs checks at Firebase here.

    // Then use setState to update the widget to a screen of choice.
    setState(() {
      if (isAdmin == true) {
        _screen = AdminScreen();
      } else if (isAdmin == false) {
        _screen = HomeScreen();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In a similar application I wrote, I had to build widgets in a screen based on the content of some web API. I used a method similar to this, and it works like a charm.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am try this method but have issue. User can only read Firestore db if authenticate (security rule). But if user is sign out, he is not authenticate. So now my code is break because it try read Firestore without permission if user logged out. I have try place the methods which read Firestore in conditional suggested by @blaneyneil above. This should make sure the methods only run if firebaseUser is authenticate: if(_auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((firebaseUser){
}) != null){ . But the methods are ignore this conditional and run anyway. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand the problem. It seems to me that you could solve this by simply wrapping the sensitive Firebase calls inside an if-statement that checks whether the user is logged in. Am I missing the point?

Comment: Thanks for reply! Actual I have solve that issue now. Your code is now work sometimes - so give correct loading indicator and then switch to correct screen when finish firebase checking. But other times the loading indicator just keeps there - no change screen. You know what issue is? If put _doSomeFirebaseChecking() function in build method this issue no longer happen. But this obvious not good solution because it keep rebuilding widget so use a lot of processing. Maybe is problem with put _doSomeFirebaseChecking() in initState()? Maybe it is not set _screen to HomeScreen()?

Comment: ^Note I added Widget to return _screen in Scaffold body because otherwise 'Missing concrete implementation of State.build'. But I not think that can cause this issue.

Comment: It might be that some `else` clauses aren't covered for; the loading widget is only replaced if you tell it to. But honestly, I don't think I can answer that without the code. This might be outside of the scope of your original question.